# How can i handle download firefox dialogbox (accept download and cancel it ) + selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to download files from firefox but i can't handle save dialogbox even i used firefox profile as below.
in fact , i want to accept and cancel dialogbox to continue the test but in my case it save the file but the dialogBox still displayed .

```
 else if(browserName.equals("FF")) {
      
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
             prop.getProperty("FirefoxDriver_win64"));
   
   FirefoxOptions FfOptions = new FirefoxOptions();       
   FfOptions.setCapability("marionette", true);  
     
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.panel.shown", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsksaveToDisk", "application/x-msexcel,text/html,application/xop+xml,application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.wap.wbxml,application/octet-stream,application/x-authorware-bin,application/x-bcpio,text/plain,application/x-msdownload,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/x-excel,application/x-msexcel");       profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel");
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","C:\\Users\\PC\\git\\downloadFile");

     FfOptions.setProfile(profile);
     driver = new FirefoxDriver(FfOptions);
 }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use Robot class to deal with popups live save dialogue open file dialogue
this link will help you to understand further.[Usage of Robot Class](https://www.guru99.com/using-robot-api-selenium.html)